# is there a way to build separate application as rate limiter in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, rate-limiting

i have a micro service that contains at least 20 microservice that they work together.
and i want to build a rate limiter that limits API by IP address of users. the problem is that we need it to be as an separate server that can do the job of rate limiting of all of micro services.

i searched about this and all i found was guava and other components that could do this job for an specific spring app . but i want separate application for rate limiting.
is there a way for doing this job separately ?
what should i do ? what component i should use ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bucket4J](https://github.com/vladimir-bukhtoyarov/bucket4j), which is a library agnostic of any web framework, that you can use to implement rate-limiting.

Also, [Guava Rate Limiter](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) can be used in the same way, it's not tied to spring boot.

Comment: tnx but for some reasons we decided to avoid using token bucket algorithm. because we want it to rate limit by user or IP address

Comment: @SamanEbrahimpoor token bucket algorithm does not prevent you from limiting by IP or by user.

Comment: i didnt know that. is it possible using Bucket4j?

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway#overview) has rate limiting and fits microservice architecture with a dedicated gateway. However, documentation seems quite scarce.